# Django Fobi - runserver URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) Page Not Found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

In order to be able to quickly evaluate the django-fobi, a demo app (with a quick installer) has been created (works on Ubuntu/Debian, may work on other Linux systems as well, although not guaranteed). Follow the instructions below for having the demo running within a minute.

Grab the latest django_fobi_example_app_installer.sh:

wget https://raw.github.com/barseghyanartur/django-fobi/stable/examples/django_fobi_example_app_installer.sh

Assign execute rights to the installer and run the django_fobi_example_app_installer.sh:

chmod +x django_fobi_example_app_installer.sh
./django_fobi_example_app_installer.sh

Open your browser and test the app.

Dashboard:

```
URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/fobi/

Admin username: test_admin

Admin password: test
```

Django admin interface:

```
URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/

Admin username: test_admin

Admin password: test
```

After running all these command and also pip install django-fobi, the result of the runserver website url was 'Page Not Found'. [But there are no pending migrations, and everything working normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ybk4.png)

[Also the urls.py seems to be okay. Can anyone solve this? thx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTaGc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have `DEBUG=True`, you will see available urls, like on
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ9aV.png)